# Qt application on i.mx35 with windows CE 6.0

Tags: qt, windows-ce

I'm having a i.mx35 board on which the windows CE 6.0 present. need to know

1. will it run or debug the Qt application? or should i port the embedded Linux on the board for development, cause Qt does not support windows CE directly and i don't have any SDK to develop app for it.
2. will it support instrument cluster type graphics, created in Qt Quick (which having qml Flies)?

any idea on this.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/wince-with-qt-introduction.html

Comment: thanks @nnb for quick reply I had read the documentation already it's all about the Windows CE 5.0, the SDK provided by windows. but for windows CE 6.0 i didn't find any sdk which creating the problem i have configured the Qt with the VSMC2005 by using nmake /I command, with QT addin [link](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/633). it through error WINDOWS600 SDK not found.